# sysopen example doesn't work

Tags: perl

I got this perl example that's suppose to demonstrate `sysopen` and `printf`, except so far it only demonstrates die.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl  
$filepath = 'myhtml.html';
sysopen (HTML, $filepath, O_RDWR|O_EXCL|O_CREAT, 0755) 
    or die "$filepath cannot be opened.";
printf HTML "<html>\n";
```

but when I execute the code it just `die`s.

```
myhtml.html cannot be opened. at file_handle.pl line 7.
```

`myhtml.html` does not exist, but it should have been created by the `O_CREAT` flag. shouldn't it?

---

**EDIT**

I have edited the code to include the suggestions about `use strict` and `$!`. Below is the new code and its result.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
$filepath = "myhtml.html";

sysopen (HTML, '$filepath', O_RDWR|O_EXCL|O_CREAT, 0755) 
    or die "$filepath cannot be opened. $!";
printf HTML "<html>\n";
```

output, due to the `use strict`, gave us a whole bunch of errors:

```
Global symbol "$filepath" requires explicit package name at file_handle.pl line 3.
Global symbol "$filepath" requires explicit package name at file_handle.pl line 5.
Bareword "O_RDWR" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at file_handle.pl line 5.
Bareword "O_EXCL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at file_handle.pl line 5.
Bareword "O_CREAT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at file_handle.pl line 5.
Execution of file_handle.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Based on everyone's suggestion and help, here is the final working code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Fcntl;

my $filepath = "myhtml.html";

sysopen (HTML, $filepath, O_RDWR|O_EXCL|O_CREAT, 0755) 
    or die "$filepath cannot be opened. $!";
printf HTML "<html>\n"; 
....
```

Comment: What is the value of `$!` after sysopen fails?

Comment: Including `$!` in your die messages should be a reflex. It should take you longer to write a die message *without* it, because you have to stop and think about whether `$!` could have any relevant information before you decide to omit it.

Comment: You could read more about `$!` and other special variables by using `perldoc -v '$SPECIAL_VARIABLE_NAME'` or by searching in: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html. For example, to read just about `$!`, you could use: `perldoc -v '$!'`.

Comment: The changes didn't create the errors; the errors were already there and `use strict;` simply revealed them. Fix them...

Comment: yeah, i sort of realized that about 2 seconds after i typed that comment...

Comment: @ikegami well, at least one of the changes is creating an error. Namely, `'$filepath'`

Comment: @hobbs, no, `$filepath` was present and undeclared in the original. Not a mjor error, but it was there.

Comment: @ikegami no, `'$filepath'`, with the single quotes, as in the revised code was trying to open a file named dollar-sign-filepath. It's been fixed now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`O_RWDR`, `O_EXCL`, and `O_CREAT` are all constants defined in the `Fcntl` module.
Put the line

```
use Fcntl;
```

near the top of your script.

You can limit the imported variables as follows.

```
# import only needed constants.  
use Fcntl qw(O_CREAT O_WRONLY O_TRUNC);
```

Comment: sean's answer is correct, and detailed, but mob's answer is very to the point. :)

Answer (score 8):

Lots of issues here:

- Always put `use strict;` at the top of your program.  That would provide a clue.
- The reason the `sysopen` failed is in the `$!` variable.  You should generally include it in any `die` message.
- As the `sysopen` entry in `man perlfunc` explains, the various `O_*` constants are exported by the `Fcntl` module.  You need to `use` that module if you want those constants defined.  As it is, you're character-wise or-ing together the strings `"O_RDWR"`, `"O_EXCL"`, and `"O_CREAT"`, resulting in another string that `sysopen` doesn't know what to do with.  `use strict` would prevent this from happening.

Comment: Sean, what does it mean when it complains about global symbol $filepath requires explicit package name?

Comment: `use strict` requires you to declare every variable with `my`.  So, you need to say `my $filepath = 'myhtml.html';`.  In your `sysopen`, you need to say just `$filepath` instead of `'$filepath'`.  And you still need `use Fcntl;` at the top of the program.

Comment: yours, mine, ours what's the difference? :)

Answer (score 1):

`myhtml.html` file probably already exists. It is probably because a previous execution of the script created it. The `O_EXCL` flag will cause [`sysopen`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html) to fail if the file exists. Relevant quote from [`sysopen`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html) documentation:

> In many systems the `O_EXCL` flag is available for opening files in
>   exclusive mode. This is not locking: **exclusiveness means here that if
>   the file already exists, `sysopen()` fails**.

Comment: that myhtml.html does not exist, I checked.

Comment: My answer seems to address a problem that you *may* encounter in the *future*. So, please see *[Sean](http://stackoverflow.com/users/182693/sean)*'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12207924/66353). :-)